# Classes and interfaces wont resolve in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to implement IRouteContraint in a helper class, but VS doesn't resolve it.
As you can see in the image, I have imported `System.Web.Routing`. I have checked from object explorer, System.Web has System.Web.Routing, which has IRouteConstraint interface. But it won't resolve.
It doesn't resolve some other classes in System.Web either, like `HttpContextBase`(which is in the image as well, without blue color).
IRouteConstraint resolves in Controller classes though.

I have restarted VS, restarted the machine. Won't work. The same thing works in another project though :(
Where should I be looking?

Update:
The solution won't compile.
System.Web itself won't resolve. Happens only in this class. I have placed it in Custom folder in root level directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your Intellisense settings have been messed(due to Resharper or other tools). Reset all settings of VS 
(I have VS 2012 Express) I do this:

`Tools > Settings > Reset`

EDIT: On VS 2012 Ultimate I can do this:

`Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings`

Comment: I cant build the solution, which means its not an issue with the editor.

Comment: You can build the solution so there seems to be no problem with the resolver. The problem is the intellisense not reading the resolver's output.

Comment: I told the solution fails to build in my first comment.